# how to display 10 values of a list which is having 100 values in angular datatable?

Tags: angular

I have a list having 100 values and i need to display first 10 values by iterating the list in angular datatable?

```html
<tr *ngFor="let i of arr">
  <td>{{i}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You have an army of `Pipes` which are applicable to your `Arrày`. Moreover, you can create your customize pipe adapted to your very specific processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Doc of Angular you can use `SlicePipe`  https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of arr | slice:0:10">
  <td>{{i}}</td>
</tr>
```

OR

Try this

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of arr.slice(0, 10)">
  <td>{{i}}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope useful

Comment: it is working, Thank you

Comment: @BhargaviAnde, welcome; Thank you to accept my answer